# JavaScript: remove duplicates from last in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to eliminate the similar array of objects with the referent of name key in object with this function **`getUniqueListBy`** but it's giving the output by deleting the first duplicated elements in the array

> I want to delete the duplicated from last by reference with the name

**Sample input:**

```
[
  { name:'shanu', id:1 },
  { name:'bhanu', id:2 },
  { name:'chary', id:3 },
  { name:'shanu', id:4 },
  { name:'rahul', id:5 }
]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[
  { name:'shanu', id:1 },
  { name:'bhanu', id:2 },
  { name:'chary', id:3 },
  { name:'rahul', id:5      
]
```

**What I did:**

```js
function getUniqueListBy(data, key) {
  return [
    ...new Map(data.map((item) => [item[key], item])).values(),
  ];
}

const data = [ { name:'shanu', id:1 }, { name:'bhanu', id:2 }, { name:'chary', id:3 }, { name:'shanu', id:4 }, { name:'rahul', id:5 } ];     
const arr1 = getUniqueListBy(data, "name");
console.log(arr1);
```

**Current Output:**

```
[
  { name:'bhanu', id:2 },
  { name:'chary', id:3 },  
  { name:'shanu', id:4 },
  { name:'rahul', id:5 }    
]
```

it's deleted the first item but I want to delete similar data from last.

Comment: You are not actually deleting here, you are _overwriting_. So you could reverse your array first, then do the mapping as you currently do, and then reverse the result again ...

Comment: Please accept an answer as the solution if the problem is solved to close the question.

Answer (score 4):

The `Map` is overwriting the following values of the same key.

You can use a `Set` to store the added keys and return the final array using `Array#reduce`:

```js
const getUniqueListBy = (data = [], key) => {
  const set = new Set();
  return data.reduce((arr, e) => {
    if(!set.has(e[key])) {
      set.add(e[key]);
      arr.push({...e}); 
    }
    return arr;
  }, []);
}

const data = [ { name:'shanu', id:1 }, { name:'bhanu', id:2 }, { name:'chary', id:3 }, { name:'shanu', id:4 }, { name:'rahul', id:5 } ];    
const arr = getUniqueListBy(data, "name");
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data =[
{
name:'shanu',
id:1
},
{
name:'bhanu',
id:2
},
{
name:'chary',
id:3
},

{
name:'shanu',
id:4
},
{
name:'rahul',
id:5
},
]

function getUniqueListBy(data, key) {
  return [
  ...new Map(data.reverse().map((item) => [item[key], item])).values(),
  ].reverse();
}

const arr1 = getUniqueListBy(data, "name");

console.log(arr1)
```